# Building a report from a runtime generated datatable

Tags: c#, datatable, reporting

I have a datatable with some data I have read from a CSV file (you helped me yesterday with that, thanks). Now, I want to show a report with some columns of that datatable.

It would be easier if I could see the fields and select them from the report designer: I'd just have to drag them to the columns. The problem is that this datatable is generated in runtime, so I can't use the designer.

How could I do that? How to make a report with data generated in runtime, and then visualize it in a reportviewer?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: even if the data is generated at runtime you should still know the layout of the tables right? If so just map them to the table. Database data is usually not static and that shouldn't matter anyways.

Comment: But how? If I try to set the value " =Fields!Vendor.Value " in a field of the designer, I have a compiler error because there is no data source binding to the report.